# Is there a way to validate that methods and attributes listed in a Python class docstring exist within the class?

Tags: python, continuous-integration, docstring

When writing docstrings for a class I wondered if there was a Python package that would parse the doc string of a class and validate that the class has the methods and attributes listed?

My motivation is for something that could be used as part of CI/CD pipeline to check that new code is documented correctly. PEP 257 does seem to suggest that class methods should be listed in the docstring, but I know listing the methods might be a contentious topic.

Consider my example class below :

```
"""An example module to ask a question on SO."""


class ExampleClass:
    """
    An example class.

    Attrs:
    ------------
    typo_ : str
        mistake I made

    Methods
    --------------
    my_method()
        method which doesn't exist

    """

    typo: str

    def my_methd(self) -> None:
        """Typo in the name."""
        return
```

Note that the attribute and method I define are mistyped in the docstring as a example of what I am trying to catch.

I have tried the following packages (which all pass without detecting any problems):

- Interrogate (1.5.0)
- pydocstyle(6.3.0)
- pydoctest (0.1.22)
- ruff (0.2.2)
- darglint2 (1.8.2)
- docsig (0.44.2)
- pydoclint (0.4.1)

(Note that I wanted to include links to these packages but SO prevented me from posting this question with the links in place)

Then the following package which does catch the fact that the typo attribute is not described in the docstring (it points me to [this](https://github.com/jdkandersson/flake8-docstrings-complete#fix-dco063):

- flake8-docstring-complete (1.3.0)

So I get halfway to my goal, but have yet to find anything that checks class methods. Does anybody know of any ways to achieve what I am looking to do?

Comment: well sorry if i may not have understand your question,

 to simply verify if a member (method, artt) is in the class too if its in the docstring, you can just have all the member names in a set (suitable) (using inspect ofcourse) by using some sort of identification, then have the docstring of the class.
after that, just using colons or so, seprate the member names in the docstring, store them in a set again, then match them again with the previous set (check for other elements).

this works to check the presence of members in both doc and class, please inform if you want a example code.

Comment: If you could share some example code that would be great, thank you